# How to auto-increment a column in a MySQL table?

Tags: java, php, mysql

Ok so I am making a program in Java where it sends data to a MySQL server where it makes a new account.  The table has 4 columns.  ID, e-mail, username, and password.  I know how to set the values of e-mail, username, and password but I need help setting ID.  ID will auto-increment based on the last registered ID in the table.

Example: If the last registered user had an ID of 4 then it will auto-set the new user's ID to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100 //use this if you want a certain number to start off from
```

To insert a new record into the "Persons" table, we will NOT have to specify a value for the "ID" column (a unique value will be added automatically):

```
INSERT INTO table (email, username, password)
VALUES ('email@domain','unixmiah', 'x007')
```

Comment: "If the last registered user had an ID of 4 then it will auto-set the new user's ID to 5." set ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=1, increase the auto inc by +1, start entering all the ids afterwards, if you just need the id to be 5, when you insert id 4 make sure auto inc is set to 4, next id will have 5 as a auto inc

Answer (score 1):

this is the way, you need to set your ID field to auto increment. If you have phpmyadmin you can do it easily on the UI otherwise you can do it on mysql command line.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: I am using phpmydamin and when I setup the table I set it to autoincrement but when I add values to the other 3 columns what to I set to add in the ID column? VALUES (ID, e-mail, username, password)

Comment: skip ID, it will do it for you automatically

Comment: So just do INSERT INTO table (e-mail, username, password) VALUES ("exemail","exusername","expassword");  Then it will skip the ID column if I do it this way, and have it so I don't add a value for it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the I'd field IN MYSQL client and set it to `AUTO INCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the column ID is set to auto increment in your database then when you do your insert specify all the fields except the ID field and it will automatically be populated with the next ID.